# query_posts show recent posts excluding all future posts

Tags: wordpress, posts

I'd like to distinguish between recent events and upcoming events in wordpress query_posts, any help is appreciated...

I am trying this:
query_posts( $query_string . '&post_type=great_events&monthnum=' . date( 'n', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) );

I am not sure how to exclude future posts/events.

Thanks in advance,

Tony

Comment: Thanks wedi, i just found out that the "The Events Calendar" plugin uses it's own start_date and end_date, and it's not a regular wordpress future posts.  so what i really need is to display recent posts based on post_type, and to exclude all future posts with future "start_date"...

Comment: Thanks Ovidiua2003 and Wedi for your contribution and help, it's appreciated, without you guys the net would be a boring place :)

This is the final custom query i used in Post Grid:
`post_type=tribe_events&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=3&end_date=<$today`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using The Events Calendar (https://theeventscalendar.com), their documentation is quite good.

So for your case you would not use the normal wp query, but their own like this:

```
$events = tribe_get_events( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5, //how many you want per page
    'end_date' => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) //anything up to now
) );
```

You can read more about it here https://theeventscalendar.com/knowledgebase/using-tribe_get_events/

Answer (score 0):

[Per documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/#parameters) the argument array of `query_posts()` takes any parameter that WP_Query allows.

Select the desired post stati with the [`post_status` parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters).

Use the [`date_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) to select a month although past months are unlikely to have future posts, I guess.

Comment: Thanks wedi, i just found out that the "The Events Calendar" plugin uses it's own start_date and end_date, and it's not a regular wordpress future posts.

Comment: Hope I could help anyway.

Comment: Thanks Wedi, with this I am succeeding to get the correct category: query_posts( $query_string . '&post_type=trive_events     Now what's left is how display all events with "tribe_event_start_date" less than today/current time...?

Comment: You can use the `after` parameter of the `date_query` as per the linked documentation or the `post_status` parameter likewise linked above.